# MySQl Get Data Form One table and use it for getting results from other table

Tags: mysql

i need help , i have this table . called "items"

```
id | User | name | price
```

and this table number 2 `comments`

```
id | text | item | date
```

what i need is getting the first array of ids that match an id of user like `'3'` and the array result of ids i use it to get array of rows from table 2

the first 1 table return Array of items . each user have more then one item . and each item have more then one comment . thanks

Comment: Pleae, add the code of your attempt. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think this what you need

```
SELECT comments.id FROM comments INNER JOIN items ON items.id = comment.item WHERE items.User = 3
```

you can change it as you need :)

Comment: thank you , can i user '*' to get all the row columns ?

Comment: if you use star to get all you will get the data un both tables . you can add more columns